# variable out of array

Tags: php, arrays, variables

I have this array:

```
Array
(
    [type] => champion
    [format] => standAloneComplex
    [version] => 3.15.5
    [data] => Array
        (
            [Aatrox] => Array
                (
                    [id] => Aatrox
                    [key] => 266
                    [name] => Aatrox
                    [title] => the Darkin Blade
                    [image] => Array
                        (
```

Now i want to get the [name] which is 'Aatrox' i do this with this variable:

```
$obj1['data']['aatrox']['name']
```

But that doesn't seems to work, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: In your array the second property starts with an uppercase. Use `$obj1['data']['Aatrox']['name']`.

Answer (score 2):

Array keys are case sensitive.  For the second index use `Aatrox` instead of `aatrox` as follows:

```
$obj1['data']['Aatrox']['name']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$obj1['data']['Aatrox']['name']
```

This is the correct form of it.

Arrays use a [hash table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) to store indexes and thus the hash of `Aatrox` is different than the hash of `aatrox`